# Node.js Error - Website shows "Cannot GET /"

Tags: node.js, error-handling

When I open the site page it shows Cannot GET /

I tried reading other posts about this problem, but I can't seem to fix this. I am new to this and can not figure this out myself.

```
require('./config/db');

const app = require('express')();
const port = 3000;

const UserRouter = require('./api/User');

const bodyParser = require('express').json;
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use('/user', UserRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: What is full URL you are going to test it? If it's *http://localhost:3000/* that's correct response since you aren't handling request to `/`

Comment: I am trying to make a login system, and I am trying to get the /user and /signup

Answer (score 0):

Every route inside UserRouter start with **/user**

If you did something like this :

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
  /* http://localhost:${port}/user/signup */
});

//Put at the end or will be trigered every time you call a route starting with /user
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
  /* http://localhost:${port}/user */
});
```

**signup** will be able to access logging inside **/User** route